# Why doesn't this patched asynchronous input work in Nightmarejs?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, nightmare

I was experimenting with nightmarejs tonight and I wanted to have a step during runtime that required user input.  Is there a way to get nightmarejs to allow something like this?  I modified the type() method that comes with the lib, and I was able to stop execution to enter some text. The script even finishes, but I don't see the input I typed, displayed in the text box it's supposed to go into.  I'm certain the dom selector is correct because when I use the same one and the built in type() method, the static text is there.  In the code below, prompt(msg) is a method from [sync-prompt](https://github.com/shovon/sync-prompt)  Here's the method I wrote, but it doesn't update the element on the page:

```
exports.type_async = function(selector, msg, done) {
  this.page.evaluate(function(selector) {
    return document.querySelector(selector);
  }, function(element){
    text = prompt(msg);
    element.text = text;
    done();
  }, selector);
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original `type` contains the line `element.value = text;` in the page context (inside of evaluate, but not the result callback), but you have `element.text = text;`.

Also, the value should be probably set *after* you have prompted for the input.

```
exports.typeAsync = function(selector, done) {
  var text = prompt('dynamic, blocking input:');
  debug('.type() %s into %s', text, selector);
  this.page.evaluate(function(selector, text) {
    var element = document.querySelector(selector);
    element.value = text;
  }, done, selector, text);
};
```

and it's called like this:

```
nightmare.typeAsync('#foo')
```

Comment: That is why I completely removed `text` completely from the function signature. I think you can call it like this afterwards, but I didn't try it out: `nightmare.typeAsync('#foo')`. Please check again, because it will make the function more sensible.